Doxygen not generating the documentation for a function declared inside `#ifdef X` `#endif`
I am making a library in C and writing internal documentation for it using Doxygen 1.9.4. I have a following header, included both from library source (in this case LIBRARY_SOURCE is defined) and from a program which is using my library:
/** @file
 *  File description... */

/** @brief Public function that is a part of an API */
void publicFunction();

#ifdef LIBRARY_SOURCE
    /** @brief Internal function that does things. */
    void internalFunction();
#endif

The problem is, Doxygen does not generate the documentation for internalFunction, but in the case ofpublicFunction everything is working as expected. Doxyfile's EXTRACT_ALL option does not help.
Why doesn't this work and how do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Well, I couldn't find any way to do this, so I created public and private headers and it works as it should. Won't delete the question as this may help somebody

A bit late to the party, but in the original example where did you set the LIBRARY_SOURCE? In case in the Doxyfile did you also set MACRO_EXPANSION = YES?

It appears that you are not using the latest version Doxygen. If I go the Doxygen website and read the changelog, I see in version 1.10 the next line:
issue #10472: Symbols within a namespace after a heavily #ifdef class are omitted in HTML output

Could it be that this will resolve your problem?
I know that this is not a definite answer but I'm not able to post comments.

Thank you for an answer, but, unfortunately, the issue persists even on the latest release 1.11.0 (https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html)

I'm aware that chances are only minimal, but what if you change #ifdef in #if defined ?

Nothing changed, @LexWassenberg
